# Enable 1st row & disable rest of the rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im working on asp.net with c#. I have a gridview with templatefield columns, data comes from sql database. I have link on the item template. Where initially only first row of the gridview should be enable, rest of the rows should be disable(all the rows should be visible),

My project is on booking beds for patients,where each room has 4 beds. Patient No1,Patient No2,Patient No3,Patient No4 are my gridview 4 rows with proper details of room,
i should book Patient No1 first, and that time rest of the rows like Patient No2,Patient No3,Patient No4  shouldn't allow me click(book),
when  Patient No1 is booked then  Patient No2 should be allow to book and other rows like Patient No3, Patient No4 shouldn't allow me to click(book) so on...

My problem is how can i enable the row & disable rest of the rows when the action is completed.

I have gone through many links & tried also but so far no luck as my condition seems complicated

Coding written for  gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='Application.aspx?BedNo=<%# Eval("Pat_ID") %>'>                           View </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a placeHolder to configure the appearance visibility of link

My previous response of this subject :
[Display DataGrid Column as Hyperlink Column depending on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487318/display-datagrid-column-as-hyperlink-column-depending-on-column-value/18488444#18488444)

Answer (score 0):

Set the href to javascript:; for all other rows having item index>0.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# Container.DataItemIndex==0 ? "javascript:;" :  "Application.aspx?BedNo=" + Eval("Pat_ID").ToString() %>'>                           View </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Just like ItemIndex you can also set condition based on status.... Booked or not and accordingly set the href

Comment: Thanks Mr.Patel, But how could i pass 2 values <a href='Application.aspx?BedNo=<%# Eval("Pat_ID") %>&Room=<%# Eval("RoomName") %>'>View</a>